# Copy Link Of Sharepoint Power App Form Still Redirecting To Infopath Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, infopath-form

When I tried to customize my sharepoint form which was customized by Infopath form before I noticed one thing that 'Copy Link' of sharepoint power app form still redirecting to infopath form.Is there is any solution for this issue?This issue found only in sharepoint list which customized by infopath before[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In List Settings => Form Settings set the form options to the second one

[image]

Cordially.

Comment: I already did that and power app form is showing perfectively fine in sharepoint list also,but when you copy the link and browse it still redirect into infopath form

Comment: Then delete it from Form Options if it's no longer needed

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I cannot reproduce your issue.

If I use the Power Apps custom form, users who open the shared link will see the Power Apps form (modern view) instead of the infopath form (classic form).

If the infopath form is no longer needed, you can delete it to compare the results:[image]

Comment: I already removed the infopath form using form settings and also checked by sharepoint designer, but still copy link redirecting to infopath form

Comment: If you choose the default form, then copy link to share with others, please check if the issue still exists.